# Cross-compiling for Windows Python error

Tags: python, c, linux, configure, autogen

I try to cross-compile libplist (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist) for 64-bit Windows and create a DLL from it. I downloaded mingw-w64 for Linux subsystem on Windows 10 (Ubuntu 14.04 bash) and set the environment variables (CC, CXX, CPP, RANLIB). I use `./autogen.sh --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32` to configure package. However it exits with the error:

```
configure:16825: error:
  Could not link test program to Python. Maybe the main Python library has been
  installed in some non-standard library path. If so, pass it to configure,
  via the LDFLAGS environment variable.
  Example: ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/usr/non-standard-path/python/lib"
  ============================================================================
   ERROR!
   You probably have to install the development version of the Python package
   for your distribution.  The exact name of this package varies among them.
  ============================================================================
```

In `config.log` it says:

```
configure:16813: x86_64-w64-mingw32-gcc -o conftest.exe -g -O2  -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-g$
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:8:0,
                 from conftest.c:33:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pyport.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:58,
                 from conftest.c:33:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
In file included from /usr/include/python2.7/pymath.h:4:0,
                 from /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h:77,
                 from conftest.c:33:
/usr/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h:78:3: error: #error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
 # error unknown multiarch location for pyconfig.h
   ^
configure:16813: $? = 1
```

It doesn't return this error when I try to compile it for Linux, so I thought that it's because it needs python libraries compiled for Windows x86_64. I copied the appropriate files from Windows from `C:/Python27/include` and tried to set environment variable for configuration `LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/python/include"` and `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/python/include` separately. Neither of them worked. I also noticed, that in `C:/Python27/include` there was also a file called `pyconfig.h`.Why does the script uses the one installed on Linux? Is there a way I could force it to use the other one?

My main objective would be to make a 64-bit Windows DLL from libusbmuxd (https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd), but it needs libplist to be compiled too. How could I solve this issue? Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can try libimobiledevice-win32. Although the name is a bit confusing, it builds 32-bit and 64-bit Windows versions of libimobiledevice.

You can compile libplist, libusbmuxd, libimobildevice and the various utilities for Windows using Visual Studio, avoiding the need to cross compile.

The company I work for, Quamotion, maintains libimobiledevice-win32 and we try to stay on track with the latest upstream changes.

You can download precompiled versions from the CI build, see e.g. https://ci.appveyor.com/project/qmfrederik/imobiledevice-net/build/artifacts for zip files which contain the latest bits.